# Reactjs: website failing to load nested (within `pages` folder) .jsx pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx, hosting

I am building a ReactJS website, within the pages folder I have the default: `home.jsx` and others. However, to keep it structured I put less used sites within folders in the pages folder.

Although this works on my local server (`npm start`) when I run `npm build` and upload to Hostinger (my hosting service) I get an error trying to go to that page.

Bellow I have put some screenshots to help you better understand...

[image: Website failing to work with nested .jsx pages]
[image: File Structure]
[image: App.js]

**ANY help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!!**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Route path="/Sem1" element={<div />}>
  <Route path="/Mathematics" element={<Mathematics />} />
  <Route path="/statistics" element={<Statistics />}/>
  <Route path="/GBA" element={<GBA />}/>
</Route>
```

Comment: I replaced my three lines of code with the code you provided. However, now the homepage wont even load. Do you perhaps know why?

Comment: @JackM no idea, sorry

Comment: This would only work if the `"/Sem1"` `element` also rendered an `Outlet` for the nested routes. This also won't change how the server serves up the app.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me:

After running `npm run build` and uploading the contents of the `build` file to Hostinger. I added another file to the parent directory, `.htaccess` containing....

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

From my understanding this tells the server to use the index.html file provided as the main "base of opperations" for lack of better words XD