# React app build shows 404 not found error. Anyone have solution for this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I made blog app using ReactJs. Using build files I hosted it on hostinger.
What happening is when I try to open
https://localhost:3000/blogapp/63a2f92b19a68516e244c452/How%20to%20print%20%22Hello%20world%22%20in%20java
it works but after hosting, below link shows "Oops, looks like the page is lost."
https://codenlearn.online/blogpage/63a2f92b19a68516e244c452/How%20to%20print%20%22Hello%20world%22%20in%20java.

You can open above link to see issue.
Can someone help me in this?

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />}>          
          <Route path='blogpage/:id/:title' element={<BlogPage />} />
        </Route>     
      </Routes>
    </Router>
    </>
  )
}
```

**Blogpage.js**

```
export default function BlogPage() {
  const { id, title } = useParams();
  let navigate = useNavigate();
 
  const [data, setData] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("backendApiRoute.com/getblogs",{params: { _id: id }})
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data.foundBlog);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console(err.response.message);
      });
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div>
      <!------- html code to render data on browser ---------->
    </div>
  );
}
```

**package-lock.json**

```
{
  "name": "blogapp",
  "homepage": "https://codenlearn.online",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: The image doesn't convey any useful technical information, and it takes up an extraordinary amount of space, so I've removed it.

Comment: Have you tried using any of the React browser plugins that can help debug things like this?

Comment: Take a review through the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) and then figure out which on might be applicable to the server environment where you are deploying your React application to. The general gist is that the server needs to redirect, or serve, the root index.html file that is your react app, for any sub-route page requests. How each server environment accomplishes this may be different.

Comment: See this post from a few hours prior to yours. Seems to be same issue on the same hosting service. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74927097/reactjs-website-failing-to-load-nested-within-pages-folder-jsx-pages

Answer (score 0):

It solved. I haven't created .htaccess file that's why 404 not found shows.
After adding .htaccess file in the public_html folder it works's fine.

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```